# Why did Dumbledore ask Snape to contain the injuries to his hand?

Tags: harry-potter

How did Dumbledore injure his hand?  Why did he ask Snape to contain the curse in his hand, instead of asking Mad Eye Moody to do so?  After all, Mad Eye is a close friend of Dumbledore. Why did Dumbledore choose to ask Severus Snape to deal with the curse?

Comment: You should really focus your post on one question, as opposed to 3 different ones. As well as providing some background as to what led to you thinking of these questions and some details as to why you might be interested in the answer.

Comment: I've edited out the secondary, completely different question to restrict this post to the one in the title (which is a valid question, and interesting) and avoid the question being Too Broad. If you want to ask the other question as well, please feel free to ask that as a separate question!

Comment: Have you read book 7? I'm not being sarcastic, just that the answer to both questions is _highly_ spoilery for book 7, and I'm not sure you would have asked the question if you read it. :) I might be wrong, of course!

Comment: You've posted a lot of questions in the last few days, and on pretty much every question of yours I've seen you've been given the same feedback. If you want to continue to contribute to this community, please start taking that feedback on board. It's not fair to everybody else to expect them to fix these issues when you've been told multiple times already. "Book title - Character name" is **not** a suitable question title. Ask **one** question - or several **extremely closely related** questions - per post (just being about the same character is not "extremely closely related").

Comment: Have you ever read the books or are you trying to infer everything from the movies? I have written this one million times, movies cannot be followed to provide canon information! The first question, about how Dumbledore injured his hand, is covered in Book 6, while the other two (why did he chose Snape over Moody) is covered in Book 7.

Comment: @Lefteris008 [one of OP's comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193246/why-didnt-scrimgeour-try-to-escape-in-deathly-hallows#comment529433_193252) makes me think they at least read book 6. Ken, regarding what's been said above, if anything's unclear about the feedback that's been provided to you, feel free to drop by in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631) where people can explain further on! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81998/discussion-between-lefteris008-and-edlothiad).

Comment: Related question: [Why did Dumbledore 'put on' the Resurrection Stone (Ring)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52968)

Answer (score 1):

Dumbledore injured his hand by putting on the cursed ring of Marvolo Gaunt, which contained a curse guarding the Horcrux.

He asked Snape to help him with the curse, for the following reasons:

1. Severus Snape is a Potions master, and a very good one, while Mad Eye is more of a fighter, detective, whatever, but not as good with potions and healing. Perhaps, Snape was the only person Dumbledore could think of, that was able to save him. The school matron was only second to him.
2. Dumbledore trusted Snape, as it is revealed in Book 7, when Harry sees Snape's memories in the Pensieve. Snape's grief on Lily's death was quite sincere, giving Dumbledore reasons to trust him completely.
3. Nobody should be aware of Dumbledore's research on Horcruxes, except for his trusted allies (including the Trio). If, say, Dumbledore went to St.Mungo's with his injured hand, it could leak critical information to Death Eaters, both on his research and imminent death. It was very important that this information was kept secret, and Snape was the best man you could think of to keep things secret. His capabilities in Occlumency were exceptional, he was not compromised until the end.

Comment: I'm curious why Phoenix tears wouldn't work...

Comment: Probably their use against curses is limited

Comment: I'd say Snape wasn't compromised even at the end, unless you consider Harry ratting out Snape being a double agent to Voldemort at the very last fight

Comment: @marcellothearcane [related answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14819/98028) to [Why didn't Dumbledore's use Fawkes's tears to heal his hand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14796/98028) : _Phoenix tears are not a cure all. They are a powerful healing agent for wounded flesh, poison, physical damage and disease. But Dumbledore's hand was not affected by any of these, it was affected by a powerful magical curse that was slowly and steadily spreading. Phoenix tears are not a counter spell. They could not heal a curse._